# Why can't components be added in localization mode in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, localization, windows-services

I just started creating a Windows Service; out of curiousity, selected English (United States) as the Service's Language, though localization is not part of requirements on hand.

Then when I tried dragging a Timer component into the design area of the service, I get this message:

```
"Components cannot be added in localization mode. Select (Default) in the Language Property to return to the default form and add components."
```

My question is, what does localization have to do with components?

I'm using VS2010/C#/.Net 4 with all latest service packs. Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Components have localizable properties as well.  HelpProvider would be a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Localization property back to Default and than add Timer component. The Localization property makes Designer generate resource files for languages you pick. These resource files contains texts, control positions, etc, so you can have different values for each language.

If localization is not a requirement, then better not to do it. Localization can get you additional work and confusement.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Yes, it is a not a requirment; I was just experimenting and was wondering what kind of localization will a component like Timer have. A second is a second in any culture, right?

Comment: How to change localization mode to default?

Answer (score 7):

To change localization mode to default:

Right side of main visual studio window there is a panel called "Properties".
If you do not have that, right click to form that you created(or you have one as default) and you'll see Properties bottom of that little window. Once you clicked "Properties" will appear on right side. There are few tabs in it. And for clear see close those tabs one by one from top.
Like "Accessibility", "Appearance" ex. You should see a "Design" tab. Under that there is a label "Language" one click on across it (I had Afar) and choose "Default".